# Добавить графические элементы

Tags: c#, xaml

Здравствуйте! Я новичок, поэтому извиняюсь если моя задача элементарна. Я не могу добавить графические элементы из C# в XAML.

В `graphic.xaml.cs` имею метод:

```
public void load_graph_MAS()        
{
    считывание координат картинок и их размещение в Canvas1
}
```

Но при вызове из `Main_form.cs`

```
UserControl1 gr_ = new UserControl1();
gr_.load_graph_MAS();
```

Элементы не добавляются. Когда добавил `load_graph_MAS()` в:

```
public UserControl1()
{          
    InitializeComponent();            
    load_graph_MAS();            
}
```

Стало нормально грузиться только при запуске, а при вызове метода ничего не происходило, хотя метод запускался. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

**Более подробнее код *graphic.xaml.cs* и метода *load_graph_MAS*:**

```
using System;    
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Linq;    
using System.Text;    
using System.Threading.Tasks;    
using System.Windows;    
using System.Windows.Controls;    
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Npgsql;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;    
using System.ComponentModel;    
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1    
{    
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl        
    {              
        double X1 = 0;        
        double Y1 = 0;        
        double X2 = 0;        
        double Y2 = 0;    
        public List<Line> Lines = new List<Line>();            
        NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost; Port=5432; User Id=postgres; Password=123; Database=BZ2;");              
        public UserControl1()
        {              
            InitializeComponent();            
            load_graph_MAS();
            //load_graph();            
            //graph_clear();
        }

        public void graph_clear()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Canvas1.Children.Clear");
            main_grid.Children.Clear();
            Canvas1.Children.Clear(); //не работает
        }

        public void load_graph_MAS()        
        {
            //InitializeComponent();                          
            //считывание координат Узлов
            String SQL_Query_node = "SELECT x,y FROM nodes ORDER BY id";
            String SQL_Query_node_rows_count = "SELECT COUNT(x) FROM nodes";

            NpgsqlCommand SQL_Command_node = new NpgsqlCommand(SQL_Query_node, con);
            NpgsqlCommand SQL_Command_node_rows_count = new NpgsqlCommand(SQL_Query_node_rows_count, con);

            con.Open();
            int i = 0;

            String SQL_Query_branches = "SELECT x1,y1,x2,y2,startnum,endnum,npar,id,r FROM branches ORDER BY id";
            String SQL_Query_branches_rows_count = "SELECT COUNT(x) FROM branches";
            NpgsqlCommand SQL_Command_branches = new NpgsqlCommand(SQL_Query_branches, con);
            NpgsqlCommand SQL_Command_branches_rows_count = new NpgsqlCommand(SQL_Query_branches_rows_count, con);

            //List<Line> Lines = new List<Line>();
            List<Label> Labels_st= new List<Label>();
            List<Label> Labels_en = new List<Label>();
            List<Label> Labels_Y = new List<Label>();

            try
            {
                Int32 branches_rows_count = Convert.ToInt32(SQL_Command_branches_rows_count.ExecuteScalar());
                NpgsqlDataReader Reader_branches = SQL_Command_branches.ExecuteReader();
                int[] branches_loc_x1 = new int[branches_rows_count];
                int[] branches_loc_y1 = new int[branches_rows_count];
                int[] branches_loc_x2 = new int[branches_rows_count];
                int[] branches_loc_y2 = new int[branches_rows_count];
                double[] branches_r = new double[branches_rows_count];
                String[] branches_startnum = new String[branches_rows_count];
                String[] branches_endnum = new String[branches_rows_count];
                String[] branches_npar = new String[branches_rows_count];
                int[] id_arr = new int[branches_rows_count];

                SolidColorBrush redBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
                char[] charsToTrim = { ' ' };

                while (Reader_branches.Read())
                {
                    branches_loc_x1[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Reader_branches[0]);  
                    branches_loc_y1[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Reader_branches[1]);  
                    branches_loc_x2[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Reader_branches[2]);   
                    branches_loc_y2[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Reader_branches[3]); 
                    branches_startnum[i] = Convert.ToString(Reader_branches[4]); 
                    branches_endnum[i] = Convert.ToString(Reader_branches[5]); 
                    branches_r[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Reader_branches[8]);

                    Line new_line = new Line();
                    new_line.X1 = branches_loc_x1[i];
                    new_line.Y1 = branches_loc_y1[i];
                    new_line.X2 = branches_loc_x2[i];
                    new_line.Y2 = branches_loc_y2[i];
                    redBrush.Color = Colors.Red;
                    new_line.StrokeThickness = 4;
                    new_line.Stroke = redBrush;
                    Canvas1.Children.Add(new_line);                    
                    string vl_name = "l" + Convert.ToString(Reader_branches[7]);
                    new_line.Name = vl_name;

                    Lines.Add(new_line);

                    Label lbl_st = new Label();
                    Label lbl_en = new Label();
                    Label lbl_Y = new Label();                    
                    Canvas.SetLeft(lbl_st, new_line.X1);
                    Canvas.SetTop(lbl_st, new_line.Y1);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(lbl_en, new_line.X2);
                    Canvas.SetTop(lbl_en, new_line.Y2);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(lbl_Y, (new_line.X1 + new_line.X2)/2);
                    Canvas.SetTop(lbl_Y, (new_line.Y1 + new_line.Y2)/2);

                    lbl_st.Content = branches_startnum[i];
                    lbl_en.Content = branches_endnum[i];
                    lbl_Y.Content = branches_r[i];
                    Labels_st.Add(lbl_st);
                    Labels_en.Add(lbl_en);
                    Labels_Y.Add(lbl_Y);
                    Canvas1.Children.Add(lbl_st);
                    Canvas1.Children.Add(lbl_en);
                    Canvas1.Children.Add(lbl_Y);

                    new_line.Cursor = Cursors.Hand; 
                    new_line.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(line_MouseDown); 
                    new_line.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(line_MouseMove);
                    new_line.MouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(line_MouseUp);
                    X = 0;
                    Y = 0;
                    i++;
                }
                Reader_branches.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception exo)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exo.ToString());
            }

            con.Close();            
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: @ser, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Должно работать. Вы делаете что-то не так. Покажите релевантную часть кода.

Comment: Я добавил код в предыдущий пост.
Посмотрите пожалуйста, уже не знаю как быть?

Comment: Ребят помогите, в чем может быть загвоздка?
Не могу тронуться с места уже недели 2

Comment: Выложи проект и дай ссылку.

Comment: В методе комментарий (//InitializeComponent();) раскомментировать пробовали?

Comment: Раскомментировать //InitializeComponent(); пробовал, не помогло.

Выложил:
http://dfiles.ru/files/fiexpkkc9
Там же таблица (нужен postgresql)

Comment: Ребята, кажется я нарушаю основы, вот только я не знаю что именно ))
Все работает если запускаю именно в .xaml.cs а если с .cs то графика не меняется.
Может объявлять как то особенно надо, или еще что?